# Scrollview fill_parent with "layout_weight"

Tags: android

I'm having problems when putting `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` Because spaces eats and grows all the greater .

When I have in wrap_content , it works fine , but when I turn , I have half the blank screen.

Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

My scroll (with rows static, not dinamically):

```
<ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">
```

My row

```
<LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center">
```

My space into scroll

```
<LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.1">
```

I'm trying to test all cases of scrollviews for Android ( Google ) has no deficiencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved create a new layout-land,, it seems the developers thought about how to go creating layouts, I tried to give the same layout (resizable for all views that exist), now in the same layout (portrait-horitzontal) does not work, maybe in the future can do not create a layout-land.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="Match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:gravity="center">

  <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3">




   Do try with the weights,may be it would work for you....
```

Comment: Thanks, but not show correctly,  android:layout_weight="0.7"  android:layout_weight="1.3"  == android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_weight="1.6"