# Android ScrollView Portrait Landscape resizable for all views

Tags: android

I'm trying to force the ScrollView for all resolutions, both horizontally and vertically.

That's what I'm getting "one single layout" with weight, but I have many problems.

I put a photo, so you can see that I am referring:
[image]

That you can see correctly  480x800 - 2560-1600 (or higher)

But for now I have not found a way to do it.

- Note I know (-Land -small -normal -large -xlarge) **but I'm trying to force a single layout.**
  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is create others layouts (-Land -small -normal -large -xlarge)
[Scrollview fill_parent with "layout_weight"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331573/scrollview-fill-parent-with-layout-weight)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to do this:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in your xml, maybe it's a solution.

Comment: I have 1083 lines of XML , I think it's more complicated than those two simple lines

Comment: and also I said, "android:layout_weight"